AWS Instance creation
When I launch a new instance on AWS, the existing instances aren't showing up in the console, but the websites hosted on those instances are still functioning. How can I find the existing instances?
i want to find my existing instance

After launching an instance, the EC2 management console offers a link to view the instance in the console.
This creates a filter that only shows that one instance. To view all instances, clear the filter:

